# Latest preact and typescript modules passing incorrect type

Tags: javascript, typescript, preact

When trying to react preact + typescript together I am able to pass incorrect types without raising an error.

I am trying to convert our code base from plain JS into preact and add type scripting. Everything installs via NPM fine and I can get the site itself actually running but when running a basic sanity test I notice that inputs reserved solely for numeric entrees accept strings.

I cloned a git with a "working" example of preact + typescript and even in the basic "Hello World" example, I am able to pass a string as an attribute despite there being a string only requirement.

I am probably misunderstanding something basic but this has taken like 3 hours and I am a bit at a dead end.

I have the latest preact, typescript and babel. I could just turn one of these at a time off and see where the breakdown happens but was hoping someone else had an issue similar?

Comment: A code sample would be helpful to answer this question.

Comment: Since browsers cannot run typesript it is transpiled into regular javascript, which has very little care for types. You will still have to add validation to you input.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a misunderstanding of the purpose of [TypeScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TypeScript).

TypeScript turns the development experience in JavaScript into something closer to a statically typed language like C#.

TypeScript will do nothing to sanitise user input.

If your question is "How can I protect against inputs of the wrong type?", then I believe what you are actually searching for is [form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation).